# Unable to write data on hive using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hivecontext

I am using spark1.6. I am creating hivecontext using spark context. When I save the data into hive it gives error. I am using cloudera vm. My hive is inside cloudera vm and spark in on my system. I can access the vm using IP. I have started the thrift server and hiveserver2 on vm. I have user thrift server uri for `hive.metastore.uris`

```
 val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://IP:9083")
............
............
 df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("test")
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClien‌​t
```

Comment: and the error ?

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Comment: I am directly saving the df. so where I should define the property of hive in spark

Comment: you may need to define `scratch dir` location

Comment: where should I define this location?

Comment: hive-site.xml file. google for scratch dir param.

Answer (score 0):

Probably inside spark conf folder, hive-site.xml is not available , I have added the details below.

Adding hive-site.xml inside spark configuration folder.

creating a symlink which points to hive-site.xml in hive configuration folder.

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /usr/lib/spark/conf/hive-site.xml

after the above steps, restarting spark-shell should help.