# How to read and write to hive tables from Apache Spark on Analytics Engine

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio, analytics-engine

I would like to use Spark on analytics engine from a Jupyter notebook in Watson Studio to be able to read and write to Hive tables, but it isn't clear how I can do this by just reading the Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables).  The reason that it isn't clear is that IBM Analytics Engine comes pre-configured with Spark and does not provide root access.

I have found some posts online for generic hadoop that describe creating a hive.xml with the metastore location, but it isn't clear how this is translated to the IBM Analytics Engine environment.  For example: [Unable to write data on hive using spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197712/unable-to-write-data-on-hive-using-spark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using scala ...

Skip the first two steps if you are running spark directly on the Analytics Engine cluster.

1. Create a Watson Studio Project and associate with an Analytics Engine service.
2. Create a scala Notebook that uses the Analytics Engine Spark service
3. Enter the following scala code to retrieve the HiveContext and list the Hive databases (if any)

```scala
    import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
    val hc = new HiveContext(sc)

    // uncomment and adjust the next line if you are using
    // Compose mysql for the hive metastore

    /*
       hc.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", 
         "mysql://admin:password@sl-us-south-1-portal.13.dblayer.com:32023/compose");
    */

    import hc.implicits._
    val df = hc.sql("show databases")
    df.show
```

4. Create a Dataframe from static values for testing

```scala
    val test_df = Seq(
      (8, "bat"),
      (64, "mouse"),
      (-27, "horse")
    ).toDF("number", "word");
```

5. Write the dataframe

```scala
    test_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("src");
```

6. Now verify that you are able to read the table from spark

```scala
    val read_df = hc.sql("select * from src")
    read_df.show
```

7. Open a hive session and verify you can query the table from hive

```sql
    select * from src
```